# Prettier on VS Code unfolds my code blocks on save . How to prevetn sthis?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, prettier, prettier-vscode, jsprettier

I'm using **Prettier on VS Code** with the editor.formatOnSave enabled. Every time I save my (js)|| (jsx) file and prettier runs it ***unfolds all my functions***. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

I have a large React component and would like to keep the component collapsed.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `editor.foldingStrategy` to `"indentation"` in VScode settings will resolve your issue.